# How to load a page via javascript in Cordova-android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am building an app in android using Cordova and I want to load a document stored in the app. The problem is that I do not want to use any user interface. So

```
 <a href=""></a>
```

won't work.

Is there any way to load a stored webpage using Javascript. I tried using

```
 window.location.assign("myurl");
```

But this is not working.

I know there is a webIntent Plugin https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent , but I don't want to use that as this will only be required once.

Please help if you know any method.

Comment: How about InAppBrowser plugin?

Comment: @Gandhi  Is InAppBrowser able to open HTML Files stored on Device

Comment: i thouht you wanted to open an URL from the app. It its for opening files from device, fileopener2 plugin should be fine

Comment: @Gandhi I guess I won't be needing fileopener2 because I want HTML Files stored within the app but want to open them without any User Interface

Comment: Sorry i m not able to understand your requirement